# problem Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, mysql-error-1048

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'patente' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `cars` (`patente`, `marca`, `modelo`, `color`, `fecha_ingreso`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2019-06-10 16:27:35, 2019-06-10 16:27:35)

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/crear',[
    'uses'=>'CarController@crear',
    'as'=>'cars.crear' 
]);
```

Short code to form

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6"></div>

            <form action="{{route('cars.crear')}}" method="post">

               @csrf

               <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="true">Patente:</label>

                        <input type="text" name="patente" size="6" maxlength="6" class="form-control"  required>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

**code create and show**

public function crear(Request $request){

```
    $patente=$request['patente'];

    $marca=$request['marca'];

    $modelo=$request['modelo'];

    $color=$request['color'];

    $fecha_ingreso=$request['fecha_ingreso'];
   
    $car=new Car();

    $car->patente=$patente;

    $car->marca=$marca;

    $car->modelo=$modelo;

    $car->color=$color;

    $car->fecha_ingreso=$fecha_ingreso;

    $car->save();
   

    return redirect()->back();

}

public function show(){

    $cars=Car::all();

    return view ('lista',['cars'=>$cars]);

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide code from your controller that actually shows the data being stored.

Comment: hello, updated code in the topic, Here is a summary of the method create public function create (Request $ request) {

         $ patent = $ request ['patent'];

Answer (score 0):

Just Validate Your data before store it,

```
php artisan make:request ClearRequest
```

in App\Requests\ClearRequest,

```
class ClearRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'patente'=>'required',
            'marca'=>'required',
            'modelo'=>'required',
            'color'=>'required',
            'fecha_ingreso'=>'required',
            'patente'=>'required',
            'marca'=>'required',
            'modelo'=>'required',
            'color'=>'required',
            'fecha_ingreso'=>'required'

        ];
    }
}
```

in your controller

```
use App\Http\Requests\ClearRequest;
```

in your clear method

```
public function crear(ClearRequest $request){
...
}
```

in your view file sth like this,

```
<form action="/clear" method="POST">
@csrf
  patente<br>
  <input type="text" name="patente">
  <br>
  marca<br>
  <input type="text" name="marca">
  <br>
  modelo<br>
  <input type="text" name="modelo">
  <br>
  fecha_ingreso<br>
  <input type="text" name="fecha_ingreso">
  <br>
  patente<br>
  <input type="text" name="patente">
  <br>

  modelo<br>
  <input type="text" name="modelo">
  <br>
  color<br>
  <input type="text" name="color">
  <br>
  fecha_ingreso<br>
  <input type="text" name="fecha_ingreso">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

if it is helpful yor you upvote me :)

Comment: I have a problem when entering what it tells me, the error is the following Class App \ Http \ Controllers \ ClearRequest does not exist

Comment: have you followed all setps above

Comment: use App\Requests\ClearRequest;  add this in your controller

Comment: in my controller have this code : 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Car;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Requests\ClearRequest;

 but the same error keeps coming Class App\Requests\ClearRequest does not exist

Comment: php artisan make:request ClearRequest

Comment: in ClearRequest    do like this             public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

Comment: In CrearRequest i have  public function authorize() 
    {
        return true;
    }
but it has the same error Class App\Requests\ClearRequest does not exist

Comment: ohh sorry, use  App\Http\Requests\ClearRequest;

Comment: no error appears but only redirects me to the main page and not to enter cars. Therefore, it does not let me enter the route / create

Comment: this means you are creating get request in your form, or passing empty data to controller, you must create post request with data

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to achieve that please?

Comment: Hey @FranciscoGonzálezMejías i have updated my answer

Comment: Currently my view is <form action = "{{route ('cars.crear')}}" method = "post">
                    @csrf
                    <div class = "row form-group">
                         <div class = "col-md-12">
                             <label for = "true"> Patent: </ label>
                             <input type = "text" name = "patent" size = "6" maxlength = "6" class = "form-control" required>
                         </ div>
                     </ div>
I delete all that and put his, I also delete the route cars.crear?

Comment: the problem happens that when I change "index" by list it shows me to create and to be able to see the data I have to change to "list" in the following code:
public function show () {
         $ cars = Car :: all ();
         return view ('list', ['cars' => $ cars]);

     }

Comment: I can not redirect the route I create and I can only enter data by changing "list" by "index" but it stays in the same route / list and not in its route called / create

Answer (score 0):

### CarController.php

```
public function crear(Request $request){
    request()->validate([
        'patente' => 'required',
        'marca' => 'required',
        'modelo' => 'required',
        'color' => 'required',
        'fecha_ingreso' => 'required',
        'patente' => 'required',
        'marca' => 'required',
        'modelo' => 'required',
        'color' => 'required',
        'fecha_ingreso' => 'required'
    ]);

    $car = Car::create([
        patente => $request->patente,
        marca => $request->marca,
        modelo => $request->modelo,
        color => $request->color,
        fecha_ingreso => $request->fecha_ingreso
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Your code looks fine, a bit verbose, so I cleaned it up a bit and added validation. The only other thing I can think to suggest is ensure your `Car` model has the fields added to the `protected $fillable` array.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to store a null value in a `NOT NULL` column. Make sure you are passing `patente` correctly in the request.